# Disable complete-ahead feature

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

When I press Tab to autocomplete with ZSH in Kubuntu 14.04, if the possible completions have common characters at the end of the word, those common characters show in the line that I am editing. For example:

```
➜  someDir  ls
ab123.png  ab129.png
➜  someDir rm ab<tab>
➜  someDir rm ab12.png # The cursor is on the `.` character
```

[image: zsh prompt with cursor on period.]

How might I disable this misfeature? I've looked in `~/.zshrc` and related files, which are very well commented, but I cannot find this feature defined in there nor can I find its location from casual googling.